# In LINQ query, how to order by included table column using .Include()?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, sql-order-by

I have this table structure:
[image: Two tables and a lookup table]

I have this LINQ query:

```
var query = (from p in context.People.Include("PeopleClub").Include("PeopleClub.Club")
             orderby p.Name
             select p).ToList();
```

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
var query = (from p in context.People
                              .Include("PeopleClub")
                              .Include("PeopleClub.Club")
             orderby p.Name, p.PeopleClub.DisplaySequence
             select p).ToList();
```

Update: Using Entity Framework 4.0

Update 2: I give up. See [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15683284/sort-inner-repeater-with-linq-query) for another approach. I ended up rewriting my query without the .Include().

Comment: Have you tried? Doesn't it work?

Comment: Have you Navigation Property mapped?

Comment: p.PeopleClub is valid, but I can't get access to any of the columns in p.PeopleClub. This is the error when I try: 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<blahblah.com.App_Data.PeopleClub>' does not contain a definition for 'DisplaySequence' and no extension method 'DisplaySequence' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<blahblah.com.App_Data.PeopleClub>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: What is the type of `p.PeopleClub`? Is it a navigation property targeting linking table?

Comment: What version of EF do you use?

Comment: The navigation properties are reflecting the foreign key relationships. PeopleClub is an EntityType. PeopleClubs is listed under the Navigation Properties for People and Club.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `orderby p.Name thenby p.PeopleClub.DisplaySequence`?

Comment: @TravisJ: `orderby a, b` or `OrderBy(a => a).ThenBy(b => b)`

Answer (score 3):

Try by navigation properties:

```
using System.Data.Entity;                                  // notice using

var q = from p in context.People
                          .Include(p => p.PeopleClub)      // notice lambda instead of string
                          .Include(p => p.PeopleClub.Club) // you may not need that though
        orderby p.FirstName, p.ClubPerson.DisplaySequence
        select p;
```

or regular join:

```
var q = from p in db.People
        join pc in db.PeopleClub on p.PersonID equals pc.PersonID
        join c in db.Clubs on pc.ClubID equals c.ClubID
        orderby p.FirstName, pc.DisplaySequence
        select p;
```

Comment: .Include is expecting a string, so it won't let me do that.

Comment: @scw: if you add the namespace below compiler will find an extension method accepting lambda.

Comment: @scw: See a [compilable example](http://yadi.sk/d/1-8UMsIO3aoIA) with both n.p. and join

Comment: What do you mean 'add the namespace below compiler will find an extension method accepting lambda'?

Comment: @scw: I'm talking about [this extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)

Comment: So this would work if I were using EF5? I'll have to check into this tomorrow.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27122/discussion-between-scw-and-abatishchev)